# Body is undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon

I have the following code in javascript (firefox extension)

```
var body;

var Test = {
initializeBody: function(e) {
  if (!e.originalTarget.defaultView.frameElement) {
    body = e.target.ownerDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].cloneNode(true);
  }
}
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) { Test.initializeBody(e); }, false);
```

when I want to use `body` variable in another function `Error console` writes that `body is undefined` . I understand that not all firefox pages have `body` tag defined, but it writes this message even if I load http://www.google.com

Do you know what is wrong?

thank you

Comment: Is it just a typo or are you missing an equal sign after `var Test`?

Comment: @duri Thanks it was just a typo here not in the program.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use document.body for accessing the body tag of a document

Comment: Valster Note that I want to change the body variable on `DOMContentLoaded` event. When you have more tabs open this would be problem.

Answer (score 0):

If `body` is undefined, I'd assume that nothing was assigned to it, probably because `!e.originalTarget.defaultView.frameElement` expression evaluates to `false`. What's that condition for?

Comment: it was originally without this condition. I thought that when I will add this condition there is less chance that the document will be without body tag.